# ERRO 10043 - O protocolo não está configurado no sistema

Tags: python, socket

Olá! Eu estou tentando criar um script que monitore a rede, estou tentando aprender então se tiver algo errado me desculpem.

O código que tenho

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htonl(3))

while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(2048)
    ethernet_header = packet[0][0:14]
    eth_header = struct.unpack('!6s6s2s', ethernet_header)
    print('Mac de Destino: ', binascii.hexlify(eth_header[0]), ' Source Mac: ', binascii.hexlify(eth_header[1]), ' Type: ', binascii.hexlify(eth_header[2]))
    ipheader = packet[0][14:34]
    ip_header = struct.unpack('!12s4s4s', ipheader)
    print('Source IP: ', socket.inet_ntoa(ip_header[1]), ' IP de Destino: ', socket.inet_ntoa(ip_header[2]))
```

O erro que estou recebendo é:

**OSError: [WinError 10043] O protocolo solicitado não foi configurado no sistema ou não existe uma implementação para ele**

Comment: Ped, bom dia! Parece que está tentando acessar algo que não existe para o S.O que está utilizando. Dê uma pesquisada sobre [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) e [Scapy](https://pypi.org/project/scapy/). O Ncap da ao Windows a habilidade de fazer sniffing de pacotes e o scapy é utilizado para trabalhar com o ncap + python. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Caro,

Pelo erro `[WinError 10043]`, acredito que você esteja rodando o código no Windows.

Veja no código fonte do [socket.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/socket.py) que a linha 133 se refere a este erro. Ela está dentro do `if` que verifica se o sistema é Windows (linha 111).

É possível que não seja possível "snifar" a rede com o socket usando o Windows, mas tenho certeza que é possível fazê-lo com o Linux.

Seu código me parece correto, porém antes de testá-lo no Linux, sugiro rodá-lo como administrador no Windows.

**Nota**: A sugestão do @Imonferrari é boa e pode te poupar dor de cabeça.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Consegui arrumar, vlw!! E desculpe pela demora para responder.

Comment: Opa! Que bom que ajeitou. Coloque a solução aqui para ajudar outras pessoas.